# how to removing programmatically composed pictures

Tags: android, imageview

I create imageview programmatically. but after I finish game this imageview cannot close how can i close, remove this imageview.
if I use this code     image.setImageResource(0);  just last image closing but I want to close all image

```
 final ImageView image = new ImageView(getContext());
    image.setImageResource(id);
    image.setLayoutParams(params);
    layout.addView(image);
```

Comment: You can make image view invisible by doing this - imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: This do just last imageview  invisible  but ı create  five image and  my code doing all imagevie name image i Think

Comment: DONT do like this Use only one image view and replace the images in the imageview or 
In your case you can make whole layout invisible which contains the all imageviews

Comment: can you add proper code about what you are doing actually?

Comment: I do black jack game and  user every pushes hit I creating  new Imageview . if user >21 all imageview close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great!!! This is my solution..

```
    final ImageView [] image = new ImageView[5];

    
    image[userartis]=new ImageView(getActivity());
        image[userartis].setImageResource(id); image[userartis].setLayoutParams(params);
        layout.addView(image[userartis]);

      for (int i=0;i<=userartis;i++){
                                image[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                             
                            }
```